# Корень в слове «пожар»

Tags: этимология, морфемный-разбор, корень-слова

Хотела бы узнать, почему в слове «пожар» корень «пожар». В словарях и интернете объяснений подробных не нашла.

По моей логике однокоренные слова (и подходящие по смыслу) - жар, жарка, прожарка, пережарить. В общем к слову «жар» добавляются разные приставки и суффиксы. В слове пожар «по» может быть приставкой, так как такая приставка существует в русском языке. 
 В этимологическом словаре Фасмера указывается, как образовалось слово:

Происхождение, этимология: пожа́р

род. п. -а, укр., болг. пожа́р, цслав. пожаръ, сербохорв. по̏жа̑р "лесной пожар", словен. роžа̑r, чеш. роžár, польск. роżаr, н.-луж. рóžаr. От по и жар. — почему же тогда мы «по» превращаем в корень?

Comment: *Хотела бы узнать, почему в слове «пожар» корень «пожар».* - а какой источник это утверждает? Добавьте в ваш вопрос, пожалуйста, воспользовавшись ссылкой [Править](https://rus.stackexchange.com/posts/467006/edit)

Answer (score 2):

Слово «пожар» действительно имеет корень «-пожар-»:

> Корень: **-пожар-**
>
> [[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80)]

---

С слово «пожар» действительно произошло от «по» + «жар»:

> **Пожа́р** род. п. -а, укр., болг. пожа́р, цслав. пожаръ, сербохорв. пȍжȃр «лесной пожар», словен. роžȃr, чеш. роžár, польск. роżаr,
> н.-луж. рóžаr. От по и жар.
>
> *[Этимологический словарь русского языка М. Фасмера]*

---

Однако приставка «по-» вошла в состав корня, и образовался новый корень «-пожар-».

> **Еще одна особенность поведения приставок в существительных — их свойство становится частью корня.** Происходит это тогда, когда корень перестает быть продуктивным, то есть без префикса никакие слова от него не образуются, и он не воспринимается как значимая морфема сама по себе.
>
> Список таких слов непостоянен, и не все сходятся во мнении, стала ли приставка частью корня. В качестве примеров приводят такие случаи: *пример, привет, природа, прибор, причуда*.
>
> Если посмотреть внимательнее, то корни здесь вполне продуктивные. Другое дело, что словообразовательные модели, по которым образовывались эти слова, сейчас встречаются все реже. Они образованы приставочно-суффиксальным способом, а точнее — от глаголов после усечения суффикса: *мера - мерить - примерять - пример*.
>
> Как видим, *пример*, несмотря на свое происхождение, давно перестал ассоциироваться с процессом мерки. В современном русском языке от *примерять* скорее образуют примерку.
>
> Еще сложнее с *привет*. В современном русском языке существуют слова, произошедшие от одной основы: *привет, ответ, привечать, отвечать, вече, совет, завещание*.
>
> Но все они давно живут своей жизнью и утратили связь с основой.
>
> [ [sherstinka.ru](https://sherstinka.ru/summary/osnovnye-sposoby-obrazovaniya-slov-v-russkom-yazyke/) ]

---

Сегодня «пожар» имеет значение:

> **Пожа́р**, *-а, м.* 1. Пламя, широко охватившее и уничтожающее что-н.
>
> ...
> *[Толковый словарь Ожегова]*

А слово «жар» значит:

> **Жар**, *жа́ра (-у), о жа́ре, в жару́, м.*
>
> 1. Горячий, сильно нагретый воздух, зной.
> 2. Место, где очень жарко.
> 3. Горячие угли без пламени.
> 4. Высокая температура тела. У ребёнка ж. Больной в жару.
>
>    ...
>    *[Толковый словарь Ожегова]*

Только третье значение: «горячие угли без пламени» — сохраняет смысловую связь с пожаром.

Основные значения слов разные.

> **Однокоренные слова** — это слова (лексемы) разных частей речи **с общим смысловым корнем** (примеры: белый, белеть, бело) или одной и той же части речи, но с разными приставками и суффиксами (например: белый, беловатый, беленький).
>
> *[[russkiiyazyk.ru](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sostav-slova/koren/odnokorennyie-slova-chto-eto-takoe.html)]*

Слова «пожар» и «жар» более нельзя считать однокоренными, поскольку они утратили общий смысловой корень.

Когда возникло слово «пожар» путём сложения «по» + «жар» у слова жар был не тот смысл, что сейчас или не совсем тот.

> **Жар.** Общеслав. Того же корня, что гореть, др.-инд. háras «жар», греч. termos «теплый» и т. д. Исходное *gērъ > žěrъ после смягчения g в ж перед гласным переднего ряда ě < ē и изменения «ять» в а после шипящего ж. **Первичное значение — «горящие, раскаленные уголья» (ср. пироги с пылу, с жару), затем — «тепло от них» и «жар» (и далее — «повышенная температура тела», а также «рвение, пыл»).** См. гореть (с перегласовкой е/о), жаровня, жар-птица. Ср. пыл и пылать, диал. жарки «костры», жарница «совок для углей».
>
> *[Этимологическом словарь Шанского Н. М]*

> **Жар.** Общеславянское слово, имеющее родственные в ряде других языков (в древнеиндийском haras — «жар»). **Общеславянское gerь — того же корня, что и гореть (см.), но с изменением корневой гласной и согласной.**
>
> *[Этимологический ословарь Крылова Г. А]*

Слово «жар» того же происхождения, что и «**гор**еть» и первоначально значило «горящие, раскаленные уголья». В последствии значение слова «жар» сместилось к «высокая температура».

Я не знаю, как точно образовалось слово «пожар», но исходя из того, что:

> **По-**
> 8. в словах, произошедших от словосочетаний с предлогом по, см. значения предлога по: побочный
>
> [[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE-)]

А предлог «по» может иметь значение похожее не предлог «до»:

> **По**, *предлог с дательным, винительным и предложным падежами*.
>
> ...
>
> 1. Употребляется при указании предела, границы распространения действия; соответствует по значению предлогу „до“. *Мы оба по пояс свесились из лодки.* Лермонтов, Тамань. *Приехал Харитон Иванович зимой, маленький, быстрый, закутанный в бабий платок по самые глаза.* С. Антонов, По дороге идут машины.
>
> [Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]

Таким образом «пожар» могло изначально значить: «по жар» — «по „горящие, раскаленные уголья“» или другими словами «до состояния горящих раскалённых угольев».

Похоже в чём-то по смыслу на слово «дотла» (сгореть дотла). Сгореть до состояния горящих, раскалённых угольев.

---

Однако сейчас «пожар» — это «пламя, широко охватившее и уничтожающее что-н.», а «жар» — высокая температура чего-то.

Семантика слов разошлась.

И как в случае со словом «пример», которое уже не ассоциируется с меркой, слово «пожар» перестало ассоциироваться с горящими, раскаленными угольями, а возник новый корень «-пожар-», который имеет значение «пламя, широко охватившее и уничтожающее что-н.»

С этим новым корнем образовались новые слова: пожарник *(тот кто занимается тушением пожара)*, пожарище *(большой пожар)*, противопожарный *(для тушения или предупреждения пожара)*, пожароопасный *(способный стать причиной пожара)* и т. д.

Эти слова уже не связаны по смыслу с горящими, раскаленными угольями, а связанны с пожаром — пламенем, широко охватившим и уничтожающим что-нибудь.

Answer (score 0):

> почему же тогда мы «по» превращаем в корень?

Наверно, потому что в этом слове нет значения приставки "по".

Answer (score -2):

ПоЖар, Огонь ----------[שרה]

1. פויירא / пойарэ // Пojare /// по жаръ = «Здесь Бог (פוי 56/72) сил אלהים /ЭлоГим = = פו  + + יי Господь Бог ++ ירא страшись, бойся
2. פוייער / пойа’рэ // Пoja’re /// по жа’ръ = «Здесь Бог (56/72) сил ++ יי Господь Бог ++ лес» - чтобы создать поле работы, лес выжигали, пускали пал.
3. פושר / пошер = « 1.тепловатый 2. безучастный3. тает, поднимает температуру»
4. הפשיר /ифшир // ипашир = «растопил; нагреть до комнатной температуры» - в древности, особенно зимой воду добывали, растапливая снег на печке.
5. פשה ער / паса ар // паша ар /// пажа ар = «распространился + враг»
6. - пожар  теплится
     Загадка принцессы Турандот:
     Теперь  я маленького роста
     дыханья всякого боюсь
     пролей воды, погибну просто
     подуй, завяну и завьюсь.
     Но если дует сильный ветер
     Я вырастаю до небес –
     Скажи, какое чудо я на свете,
     Что я за диво, что за бес?

---

7. פשר /пешер – «1. значение, смысл, объяснение 2. отгадка»

הוהון / havon // hoGon /// огон = «горестный, несчастный; строящий козни»
– בעת // Бэс – (ашкеназийск.)«страшись, бойся, паника»
הוהון// Оггон – « הו Бог הון божественный, смелый»;

8. פו שרף / по сараф // по шарф /// по жарф = «Здесь Бог сил אלהים /ЭлоГим = = פו  + сжигать, палить; прожигать»
9. [פשע] --- פושער / пошэар// пожар = «  פושע совершает преступление, бунтует, причиняет ущерб + ער /ar  “враг”»
10. פה השרה /по иШра = «Здесь + наполнять жидкостью»
11. פה שריה /по шриа = «здесь + погружение в жидкость»
12. (פה) פו שרה /по сара // по жара = «здесь Бог сил אלהים /ЭлоГим = = פו  + бороться, сражаться» ---- ср. ישראל /Исраэль – «боролся с Богом», т.е. с пожаром, с ущербом, наносимым врагом